# Querying parse.com using their SDK and get response as reusable Angular $scope

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform, angularjs-scope

I use [parse.com SDK](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/) in my `AngularJS` application
with this code in a controller:

```
var MyData= Parse.Object.extend('MyData');
var query = new Parse.Query(MyData);

query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.resultData = results.map(function(obj) {
                return createMyDataObjectFromParseObject(obj);
            });
        });
    }
});

function createMyDataObjectFromParseObject(parseObject){
    return {
        startDate: parseObject.get('StartDate'),
        endDate: parseObject.get('EndDate'),
        investment: parseObject.get('Investment'),
        format: parseObject.get('Format'),
        partner: parseObject.get('Partner'),
        purpose: parseObject.get('Purpose')

    };
}
```

Now I would like to use the content stored in `$scope.resultData` inside another function but whenever I call it outside the `query.find()` function it's undefined... Why is this and how can I make it store the data in a scope for later use? New to Angular so bear with me please. Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that code inside a Service Module, more especifically the `service()` method of angular, the Stackoverflow link below especify how and when to use the diferent service modules.

[AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

Comment: Thank's but is there really no other way?

Comment: No if you're following the architecture of AngularJS, also this enable the reusability of your code.